# PCA used for regression

Tags: regression, pca, references

Can anybody point me to a thorough example where PCA was used for predictive purposes and it compared favorably to regular linear regression (i.e.,  perhaps a lower RMSE using the PCA components compared to the individual x independent values)?

Comment: This is generally not a good strategy.  If you're thinking of using PCA to reduce dimensionality in regression, it would almost certainly better to use some kind of regularized regression instead.

Comment: It is a mathematical impossibility to lower the RMSE by replacing the original regressors by any set of principal components, for the simple reason that the predicted values from the PCA regression--which are linear combinations of the principal components--are *a fortiori* linear combinations of the original regressors and therefore cannot improve on the least squares solution.  What, then, do you have in mind?  Perhaps introducing nonlinear transformations of the principal components into the regression?

Comment: hello, thanks for responses.  I have seen varying statements on other blogs.  here is a statement and response.   
Variables derived by PCA can be used for regression analysis and PCA can give a better prediction and less error."
the response.   “Rightly said. PCA when used for regression takes a form of supervised approach known as PLS (partial least squares). "   my own (limited) understanding would have been that it one can use components that are derived from the potentially correlated indep variables then having non correlated indep vars would improve it.  or could improve it.  No?

Comment: It is possible to reduce *out of sample* prediction error using PCA, but not plain RMSE (as whuber indicated).

Comment: thank you.  cutting to the chase, I suppose, if I have many correlated independent variables, and I want to reduce prediction error as much as possible, is machine learning the best way to do that?  or just run a regular linear regression, take the significant coefficients, and let the chips fall where they may?

Comment: A regression on $p > m$ IVs that finds $m$ IVs which are significant is not the same as a regression comprised only of the $m$ significant IVs. This is not a sound strategy.

Comment: Definitely not the latter!  Selection based solely on p-values tends to be risky and can lead to poor results.  See our (numerous) posts related to model-building, regularization, and variable selection.

Comment: I have seen dozens of posts, but I have not found one that suggests the best approach to minimize prediction error. What I am looking for is just some guidelines. the proverbial , "if somebody put a gun to your head" and you had to find the lowest pred error for the holdout sample, and u have 50 mostly correlated IV's, what do u do? do u try by 5 different ways (trial and error) and determine the least prediction error? do u use whatever neural network your software is equipped to using?  is this a taboo question? I have looked at 30 posts,and they all seem to dance around this question.thanks